# Make a file on a different directory to what your already on

Tags: cmd, directory

I type

```
C:\>tree
```

And it comes up with a massive, never-ending list of everything stored on my laptop. I can't see all of this because cmd has a scrolling limit; I can't see above a certain number of lines.

This is what I type to save this tree as a text file

```
C:\>tree > Tree.txt
```

But I want to save this text file in my desktop. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the text file directly on your desktop folder run:

```
tree >"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Tree.txt"
```

`%USERPROFILE%` is replaced by the Windows command processor on execution by value of predefined environment variable **USERPROFILE** containing the path to the profile directory of the current user. Run in a command prompt window the command `set` to get displayed all environment variables predefined for your user account on your Windows computer.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying the path.

```
C:\> tree > some\path\to\Tree.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want to do is to copy Tree.txt from your laptop to your desktop. The simplest way of doing so is to use something like dropbox, google drive. Even emaling that file to yourself from your laptop and opening it up from your desktop would help.

And hey, there is always a flashdrive :)

More seriously tho, if networking is enabled and if these two machines are "trusted" by each other, you can use either file explorer or cygwin (if you happen to have it installed).